# Flagged question about circuits as off-topic, declined

Tags: support, flags, scope

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580522/circuit-with-3-light-bulbs

[image: Image 1]

Seems off topic to me, but my flag was declined.

Also, I was not sure which flag to choose, I chose "Needs Moderator Attention" with a note explaining "off-topic for SO". Was this the correct action?

Comment: Wasn't there a flag available with *'off-topic because...'* as the reason?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, I just went back and found this. For some reason I didn't notice that option on the mobile site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to flag that post for moderator attention; in this scenario, you want to flag for closure do to it being off-topic.

I can't speak for the moderators at all, but if I had to guess, I would imagine they declined it since you're only meant to use the moderator flags to bring something to their attention that the community *can't* adequately handle.  Flagging this for closure would adequately handle this question.

Comment: In this case, there was a custom flag that stated "Off topic for so" and it was declined with the reason "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)"